# ASP.net compilation problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, compilation, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I have come across a very interesting issue.  Here are my settings for the site in question:

- IIS7
- Sitefinity 4

I have created some standalone ASPX pages that are not hooked into Sitefinity and have an issue when it comes to compilation after making changes to the .cs files.  I will make a change in the .cs, save and refresh the site and the changes do not take effect.  If I make a change to the .aspx (putting a space character at the end of a line) compilation seems to occur and the changes previously made in the .cs are now live.

Any ideas where I should start debugging this?  Is it a strange caching issue that gets invalidated only by updating the .aspx file?  Is it a Sitefinity setting that is preventing .cs changes from causing compilation somehow?

**-------------------- EDIT --------------------**

I am opening the site via File > Open > Website, and it is .NET 4.0

Comment: This depends on which file you're changing. If you're changing in your code-behind files, then you have to compile it again in a development environment like Visual Studio.

Comment: @wegginho, not if the project is a web site instead of a precompiled web application.  Any .cs files in the App_Code folder should be compiled when accessed by a visitor to the site.

Comment: defining code-behind files: Default.aspx is a Site, Default.aspx.cs is a code-behind file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm assume you're using either .Net framework v3.5 or v4....?  I don't think early versions of .Net supported Just-in-Time compilation.

Comment: Changes to code-behind files should get compiled by the JIT compiler as well.  This is only for web site though...from VS : File > New > Web site.

Comment: I am opening the site via File > Open > Website, and it is .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe on a Sitefinity site, to see updates to your code-behind (.aspx.cs) files or to regular class files (.cs) you can either:

1. Recompile the site manually with visual studio
2. Make a change to a front-end .aspx file, which I believe forces the IIS/Cassini to recycle the application pool (because these updates are not instantaneous as in normal .net development).

Also, if you're testing with IE8 then make sure to delete your cache from the developer tools bar. I've noticed that IE will NOT dump your cache completely unless you hit F12 (dev tools bar) > HTML tab > Clear Browser Cache...

This is not a bug, AFAIK.